# How can I force Java's jSerialComm to idle for a short time between messages sent over a serial connection?

Tags: java, serial-port, outputstream, serial-communication

I'm using Java's jSerialComm package to communicate with a series of devices over a shared RS485 serial connection on several different OS setups (Windows and Linux, some with USB-to-serial adapters and others with direct serial ports). The device's requirements state that it can handle messages addressed to other devices but outgoing messages must be follow the rule below.

> The transmitting device shall guarantee a gap of a minimum of two character times before it may access the communication channel. This idle line delay is required to allow for signal converters and/or multiplexers to sense that the line has become idle.

The problem here is that jSerialComm and its internal OutputStream sends all bytes it receives out whenever it, or the underlying serial driver, wants to. I can write bytes to the output but have no way of knowing when they've been sent to the devices. So, if I have two devices and send a message to each device, one after the other, the first device will correctly receive it's message but the second device will ignore its message since there is no idle time between the two messages (it apparently assumes that both messages are just one long message for the first device).

I've tried a few things.

- Using the event listeners described in the jserialcomm [documentation](https://github.com/Fazecast/jSerialComm/wiki/Modes-of-Operation) though these would only work on a Windows system and only if the driver worked (which doesn't seem to be the case for my setup).
- Waiting an arbitrary amount of time after sending each byte[] though this is either too slow or isn't reliable across different systems.
- Adding extra 1's or 0's before or after each message. I was hoping that the either the driver would send nothing for these or the device would perceive them as an idle connection but that didn't work.

---

I think what I need is either a way to actually know when the bytes of a message have been sent or a have a way to force some idle time between messages. Does anyone know of a way to do this?

Comment: The typical method of insuring that there's an idle line between messages is to (a) have only one sender, i.e. only one thread that opens ands writes to this serial terminal. (b) Send each complete message as one system call. (c) Use a [tcdrain()](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSLTBW_2.1.0/com.ibm.zos.v2r1.bpxbd00/rttcd.htm)-type function before sending another message.   If the baudrate is slow then you may also need an explicit delay.  (d) Suggest you use an oscilloscope to verify what you are doing.

Comment: Thanks for the reply sawdust. I have point (a) covered and I can try out point (d) but is there a way to handle points (b) and (c) in Java? It seems that the Java OutputStream writes a given byte array byte-by-byte to the lower system/driver's buffer, not all at once. I don't know how to control how the data is then handled at the OS level.

Comment: *"is there a way to handle points (b)"* -- Worry foremost what you can control.  So your code must generate a complete message, and then send that complete message by the raw, direct write mechanism.  According to [this](https://github.com/Fazecast/jSerialComm/blob/master/src/main/c/OSX/SerialPort_OSX.c#L502), your message would be submitted in a single syscall.  *"...and (c) in Java?"* -- According to [this](http://fazecast.github.io/jSerialComm/), you can get a callback notification when all data has been successfully written.